# regarding the typeof() for an array like variable

Tags: r

I am processing a given R program, which generate a result variable, e.g., $video_log$, if I type

```
video_log$size
```

It outputs an array of size 1000, part of output is shown as follows.

```
> typeof(video_log$size)
[1] "double"
```

[image]
However, when I try to print its type information as follows, it output "double" instead. I am curious why the type information is not "list", "array" or a "dataframe", but "double" instead. Moreover, how to enforce this variable v`ideo_log$size` as an numerical array, and save it as a csv file.

```
> typeof(video_log$size)
[1] "double"
```

Comment: You will find that `typeof()` and `class()` will output different values for the same object. For example, a dataframe is of class `dataframe` but of type `list` (a dataframe is a special case of list in which each element is a vector of same length). Similarly, an object of type `double` will have the class `numeric`.
For the difference between type and class, this can be a start: http://rfunction.com/archives/770

Comment: In R, there are no scalars. Basically everything is an atomic vector or a list. Rather than just saying "vector", `typeof()` will always tell you the vector type. But really if you want to know how an object will behave rather than how it's data is stored, use `class()`. I've never found a use for `typeof()`. Note that CSV files are just text files and are not strongly typed. There's no standard way to put type information in a CSV.

Comment: Hadley Wickham did a nice presentation where, among other things, he discusses these atomic vectors. The link is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qne86lxjgtg) and the relevant part is 12 minutes in.